# How do I run a mirror api php script at 8 am every morning?

Tags: php, cron, scheduled-tasks, google-mirror-api

I started with the php quick start and created a new php file that fetches information from a websites and send the information to the glass. How would i send this information at 8 am every morning?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your hosting platform.

You can [create a special text file to do this](http://www.phpdig.net/forum/showthread.php?t=323) if you're using Apache server. If you're hosting your PHP files on Windows Azure, you [can use the Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495651.aspx) to make a call to your file according to the schedule you want.

Then, to send the data to Glass, you would just have the PHP file make a call to the API with the completed data. This way if you need to change when you're sending the data, you don't have to change your code, just the scheduler settings.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do, broadly speaking:

1. You need to store the user's auth token and refresh token (usually sent in an object or array, and should be stored that way). The quickstart takes actions for a user that is hitting your website, so you're fetching the tokens at that moment. You need to save them after the first time they visit your site so you can use the authorization information later when you want to send information to them.
2. You need some way to schedule a job to run at 8am every morning, trigger the job at that time, and for that job to trigger your web server to take the appropriate action. This is a problem outside the Mirror API and is usually done with something like *cron* on UNIX or *Task Scheduler* on Windows. There are several PHP packages which appear to do the same sort of thing.

**Update**: You can store the credentials using whatever data store you're familiar with. PHP has modules that work with MySQL, for example, but this isn't your only option.

Yes, you need to create and send a card for each user (ie - each auth code). Each card is permitted to one user only, so a user can delete their copy of the card without changing the card from another user.

Comment: How would i store these credentials? (sorry im just starting with mirror api here)

Comment: Also, would I have to run a loop to send the cards for every stored authorisation code?

Comment: For Scheduling, you can use www.atrigger.com

Comment: Updated with replies to your questions.